# Randomised strategies

Tags: game-theory

[image]

[image]

I don't understand what is meant my assigning probabilities to randomised strategies. Randomised strategies are themselves probability distributions over the pure strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great, this is a cautionary tale for two of my favourite don'ts:

- Don't use abbreviations when it would have cost you just a couple of key/pen strokes to write them out and the expected cost to the readership in terms of decryption effort and potential misunderstandings is much higher.
- Don't use "random" when you mean "arbitrary".

Comment: I still don't understand the solution

Comment: @Snickett: But you understand now that "rand." here means "arbitrary" and not "randomised"? What else would you like me to explain?

Comment: I actually understood randomised  strategies to be arbitrary, i.e both pure and randomised strategies. I have only before considered assigning probabilities to pure strategies, to give a randomised strategy. I have never come across assigning probabilities to randomised strategies.

Comment: @Snickett: No, they mean arbitrary pure strategies. They're assigning probabilities to pure strategies to create a mixed strategy.